# c#, is there OnChange event in ListBox?

Tags: c#, events, onchange

I've been looking for something like that but I couldn't find it. I want my program to do something when there's any change in `ListBox` (e.g. changing selected item, adding new one, removing one and so on)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) or [SelectedValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx) events.

For adding or removing items there are no .NET events, so you have to implement that functionality yourself. [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655956/how-to-detect-if-items-are-added-to-a-listbox-or-checkedlistbox-control) explains how you can accomplish that.

Good luck!

PS: I assumed you are using `Windows Forms`

Answer (score 3):

If you're binding your `ListBox` to say a `BindingList`, you can use the `BindingLists`'s `ListChanged` event. The `ListChangedEventArgs` has an argument `ListChangedType` which tells you if an item was added, removed, moved or changed.

You can do similar things with similar collections.

If you're adding or removing items yourself, you can obviously directly tell some other piece of code to execute or you can just create and raise an event yourself, provided you have a `ListAdded` event:

```
ListAdded(this, new ListAddedEventArgs() { List = myList, Item = myItem });
```

Answer (score 0):

just note, that´s not tottaly correct, best it´s once you change the content on the Listbox, do something like that additionally:

```
FilterListBox.SelectedIndex = FilterListBox.Items.Count-1;
```

In order to change the index, then you will be able to use the eventhandler for SelelectedIndexChanged.
Thanks for your help!