# How to create an event when is added or removed something in ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox-control

How can i create my own event about `ListBox` when something is added or removed from it? because my code is growing a lot and repeating the same think that i did in other areas, could some one help me ?

I was tried to override the add method putting the new keyword, but, i don't know how because has method inside propriety...

```
class NewLista : ListBox
{
    class Eventos : ListBox
    {
        public delegate void ListBoxNova();
        public event ListBoxNova ListBoxChanged;

        public new void Add(string K) //BUT, isn't work's because is ListBox.Items.ADD... 
        {

        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a BindingList and setting a event handler on changing the value in it. Set the datasource of your listbox to the binding list.

Comment: Windows forms? WPF? Web?

Comment: @LucMorin Windows Forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if items are added to a ListBox (or CheckedListBox) control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655956/how-to-detect-if-items-are-added-to-a-listbox-or-checkedlistbox-control)

Comment: @t3chb0t Negative, i got to saw that but my question is using a event keyword.

Comment: @VictorHugoPongolino as suggested by t3chb0t , you have the answer in the question itself