# Check if a ListBox item was added

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

I am trying to check if a new item got added to my `ListBox`, but I do not know how to do that. On my `Form1_Load` I am executing this code (using .NET Framework 4.7.2):

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs) 
{
     preloadedscripts.Items.Clear();
     Functions.PopulateListBox(preloadedscripts, "./Scripts", "*.txt");
     Functions.PopulateListBox(preloadedscripts, "./Scripts", "*.lua");
}
```

Since this is being executed only when the Application gets started, I want to automatically check if a new item was added, and then re-run this code.

**Info**: I don't want something like a "refresh" button.

Comment: You should know when new Items are added to a ListBox.Items collection, since your code is the only entity allowed to add one. Move that code to a method, so you can call it from wherever you need it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/655956/10216583

Comment: actually i only needed to paste the code i given into my save button